# Connection between field of fractions and smallest field $F$ containing $\alpha$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, extension-field

I have been thinking that a field $F$ and then adding in an element $\alpha \in E$ ($E$ is some larger field properly containing $F$) was denoted by $F(\alpha)$.

It seems like $F(\alpha)$ is more specifically a field of fractions where each element is a ratio of polynomials (from $F[X]$) that may involve $\alpha$. For example, $\frac{2\alpha^2 + \alpha}{\alpha^3}$ (assuming $1,2 \in F$) could be an element of $F(\alpha)$.

This somehow results in $F(\alpha)$ being the smallest field that contains $F$ and $\alpha$.

Furthermore, there is notation such as $F(\alpha, \beta)$ and $F(\alpha)(\beta)$ that to me, looks to me would result in the exact same thing.

So (assuming I am roughly correct so far), why do we start with a polynomial ring of $F$, then turn it into a field of fractions?

Why does a field of fractions result in the smallest ring containing $F$ and $\alpha$ (or, what is an intuitive explanation as to how I could show it is the smallest)?

What is an example of a result of $F(\alpha, \beta)$ being different from $F(\alpha)(\beta)$?

Comment: $F(\alpha,\beta)=F(\alpha)(\beta)$.

Comment: And the reason why the notions are equivalent is that fields need to be closed under division, which is why you expect all the fractions to be in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's make it clear. Suppose $E/F$ is a field extension, $S\subseteq E$ is a subset. (might be an infinite subset as well) Then $F(S)$ is the smallest subfield of $E$ which contains the field $F$ and the set $S$. The meaning is smallest by inclusion, i.e if $K$ is a subfield of $E$ which contains $F$ and $S$ then $F(S)\subseteq K$. Now how do we know such smallest field really exists? Because we can take all the subfields of $E$ which contain $F$ and $S$ and intersect them. It is easy to check that the intersection is a subfield which contains $F$ and $S$, and obviously it is the smallest with such property.

Ok, so we know $F(S)$ really exists. However, the method I described (taking the intersection of all such subfields) doesn't give us much information about how the elements of $F(S)$ look like. So we would like to find another way to describe this field. And it really can be described like that:

$K=\{\frac{p(s_1,...,s_n)}{q(t_1,...,t_m)}: n,m\in\mathbb{N}, p\in F[x_1,...,x_n], q\in F[x_1,...,x_m]\, s_1,...,s_n,t_1,...,t_m\in S , q(t_1,...,t_m)\ne 0\}$

It can be checked that this set is a subfield of $E$ which contains $F$ and $S$. Hence $F(S)\subseteq K$. Now why is $K$ exactly $F(S)$? Because any field which contains $F$ and $S$ must be closed under sums, products and fractions of their elements, i.e any such field must contain all the elements from $K$.

What I described is the general case, now $F(\alpha)$ is when we take $S=\{\alpha\}$, a set with one element. And $F(\alpha,\beta)$ is when we take $S=\{\alpha,\beta\}$. Note that $F(\alpha,\beta)$ and $F(\alpha)(\beta)$ is really the same thing. Let's show this.

$F(\alpha)(\beta)$ by definition contains $F(\alpha)$ and the element $\beta$. From here it follows that it contains the field $F$ and the elements $\alpha,\beta$. So $F(\alpha,\beta)\subseteq F(\alpha)(\beta)$. On the other hand, $F(\alpha,\beta)$ is a field which contains the field $F$ and the element $\alpha$, hence $F(\alpha)\subseteq F(\alpha,\beta)$. But it also contains the element $\beta$, so $F(\alpha)(\beta)\subseteq F(\alpha,\beta)$.

Comment: thank you, that clarifies a lot. could you please explain further (not formally) why we represent elements as fractions like that though? i dont have any intuition as to why it makes sense to do it that way.

Comment: The intuition is like in the way we represent the span of a set in vector spaces. The elements in the span of $S$ are linear combinations of elements of $S$, because a vector space must be closed to addition and multiplication by a scalar. Similarly, here we want $F(S)$ to be closed under all the field operations. So just taking elements of the form $p(s_1,...,s_n)$ is a good start, such elements are closed under addition and multiplication. But it might not be enough, because we need the field to be closed under fractions as well. So that's why we take fractions of such polynomials.

Comment: so even when we just want to add a single element (ie, a set with cardinality of 1 and a span of 1), we just always use polynomials? my linear algebra is very weak. thanks.

Comment: Yes. If we just add the element $\alpha$ and nothing else then we will usually not get a field. To get a field we have to close it under all the field operations. So in the general case we take fractions of polynomials, which are elements of the form $\frac{p(\alpha)}{q(\alpha)}$. This is the general case. Also, in some specific cases there are theorems which can make it a bit easier. For example, if we know $\alpha$ is algebraic over $F$ then there is a theorem which says it is enough to only take the elements $p(\alpha)$, it will already give us $F(\alpha)$.